# Swift UIDatePicker for text field input - how to make UIDatePicker disappear?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my first ever attempt at Swift or an iPhone app, so needless to say I'm not sure how to do many things at this point.

Right now I have a view controller with a text field and a button. I've managed to find example code to almost accomplish what I need. I'd like to do the following:

1. When I click into the text field have a `UIDatePicker` come on screen.
2. Set the `UIDate` picker to display time only - not a date.
3. Put the selected `UIDatePicker` time in the textfield.
4. Have the `UIDatePicker` go away when I click on the button.

1 through 3 is working. But I can't figure out how to have the `UIDatePicker` go away and still come back on the screen if I click into the text field again.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func dateField(sender: UITextField) {

        var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    }
    @IBAction func DoneButton(sender: UIButton) {

        //How to make datepicker disappear???
    }

    func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        var timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
        dateField.text = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code helped me sort out my datepicker.. thanks!

Comment: MGann howd you make it so that once the field is clicked the keyboard doesnt show but the DatePicker thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call `resignFirstResponder` on the text field:

```
@IBAction func DoneButton(sender: UIButton) {
    dateField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Also, it's not a great idea to have a method and a property with the same name - not sure about precedence there, but chances are it could be confusing at some point.

Comment: Hi Nate - That was it! Thanks for the help! Also thanks for the comment on the name of the method and property, I'll be sure to change that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something as `gestureRecognizer` to make the UIDatePicker disappear:

```
@objc func viewTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   view.endEditing(true)    
}
```

This is what I used in my app so when the user taps on anywhere on the screen the UIDatePicker goes away!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create an outlet for the datePicker.
 @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIPickerView!

then in your function

```
@IBAction func DoneButton(sender: UIButton) {

    datePicker.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: You do realize that the date picker is an input view for the keyboard right?.... Dismissing first responder is the proper way to get rid of a keyboard view, not hiding the containing view....

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it updated for Swift 5 using only one `IBOutlet` for the date text field and doing the rest programmatically.

There is a good video of this implementation by "Swift with Yash" on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NngJrVFfUw

### Swift 5

```
class viewController: UIViewController {
    
    // This is the IBOutlet to your date text field in storyboard
    let dateTextField: UITextField!

    // We will use this to configure the date picker
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Call function to set up date picker
        createDatePickerView()
    }


    // Call this fxn in ViewDidLoad to set up the date picker
    func createDatePickerView() {

        // Set your preferences for datePicker mode/style
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.wheels
        
        // Create toolbar where a "Done" button will go
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
    
        // Create Done button
        let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
        toolbar.setItems([doneBtn], animated: true)
        
        // Assign toolbar to the top of the text field input view
        dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        
        // Assign date picker as the input view for the text field
        dateTextField.inputView = datePicker
    }


    // This function is called when the Done button is pressed
    func donePressed() {

        // Create formatter to make date more readable
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        
        // Show formatted text in date text field
        dateTextField.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        
        // Close date picker
        self.view.endEditing(true)    
    }

}
```